# ANT+ Single Channel Encryption example

Tags: encryption, channel, garmin, antplus

I'm working with ANT+ protocol, to connect a smartphone with an ANT+ USB dongle, which is connected to PC where with SimulANT+. SimulANT+ is simulating a heart-rate sensor, which sends data to my phone.

Until now I have been using a non-encrypted channel to communicate, but there is also an option to make a secure connection between devices as is written in [ANT Message Protocol and Usage document](http://www.thisisant.com/developer/ant/ant-basics#104_tab). It's called Single Channel Encryption. Do someone have some code examples on how to establish this type of connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that ANT protocol can use a single encrypted channel - however this is not the case for ANT+. (See the differences between ANT/ANT+ here: http://www.thisisant.com/developer/ant-plus/ant-antplus-defined)

If you use encryption for your device it is no longer ANT+ compliant and therefore you are not allowed to use the ANT+ Network Key or frequency.

This is because ANT+ aims to ensure interoperability between different manufacturers sensors/displays. If the channels were allowed to be encrypted, this would defeat the purpose ANT+.

Therefore if your goal is to use your device with SimulANT+ (or any existing ANT+ sensor) it will not work. In fact, SimulANT+ does not even allow the utilization of encrypted channels.